# In VirtualBox Headless Mode can I display the UI on demand?

Tags: virtualbox, headless

I would like to auto-launch my Virtual Machines in Headless Mode, while being able to launch the GUI on demand. This user experience would be nearly identical to using a remote desktop session to connect to another running machine. The system is always running, and I am able to log in/out as needed.

Is it possible to do this with VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post [Is it possible to launch GUI of headless VirtualBox' machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/469501/is-it-possible-to-launch-gui-of-headless-virtualbox-machine) apparently you can start the GUI while the VM is already running.

Comment: Please quote and cite the relevant information from your link, even though, it's another answer from this website